# Best way to set keys and default value of an object based on values from an array in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object

I am new to TypeScript and feel like I am missing something.

What I want to do:

- I want to make an object `emptyEntry` with all properties being an empty list instead of undefined at first
- I know which properties I will be needing, these properties are the `name` properties of an Array `arr`
- Eventually, I want to be able to push elements to the properties of `Entry`
- I want to be as strict as possible and use Typescript in an optimal way

```js
const emptyEntry = {
  key1: [],
  key2: []
}
const arr = [{
    name: 'key1'
  },
  {
    name: 'key2'
  }
]
emptyEntry['key1'].push({
  pushedItem: 'pushedItem1'
});
```

What I have tried:

1. Create a type called `Entry` with keys based on `arr` when set as readonly (`arrKey`)
2. Create a function `createObject` that takes in a list parameter and first creates an empty object `obj` with dynamic keys. It then loops over the list parameter and sets all the properties of the new `obj` to an empty array. It finally returns `obj` as a type of `Entry`.
3. Call `createObject` and pass in the mapped variable called `keys` made from the name values of `arr`.
4. I can now push items to the keys since they already exsisted as empty arrays.

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'key1'
}, {
  name: 'key2'
}] as
const
  type arrKey = typeof arr[number]['name'];
type Entry = {
  [k in arrKey]: object[]
};

const createObject = (keys: string[]) => {
  const obj: {
    [k: string]: any
  } = {};
  keys.forEach(k => {
    obj[k as keyof typeof obj] = [];
  });
  return obj as Entry;
};

const keys = arr.map(k => k.name);
const emptyEntry = createObject(keys);
emptyEntry.key1.push({
  pushedItem: 'pushedItem1'
});
```

What I would like to know:

- I feel like my approach is not very TypeScript-ish. Is there a better way to do set an `Entry` type with default empty array values?
- Since I will be pushing items to the arrays many times and with more complicated functions, I was wondering if I could set up a class. The thing I struggle with here is that the constructor of the class should set keys based on `arr`. I do not want to set them by hand if possible.
  I tried something like this but I couldn't get it to work

```js
const arr = [{
  name: 'key1'
}, {
  name: 'key2'
}] as
const
const keys = arr.map(k => k.name);

class Entry {
  constructor() {
    keys.forEach(k => {
      this[k] = [];
    });
  }
  add(key: string, pushedItem: {}) {
    this[key as keyof Entry].push(pushedItem);
  }
}
```

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a class with the `key1`, `key2`, etc., as automatically included members won't work, because [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) (which you're using for `Entry`) aren't compatible with classes. (A class could `implements` a mapped type, but it would have to explicitly set out every member from the mapping.)

The key issue I see in terms of TypeScript-ness is that the arrays are typed as `object[]` instead of something more specific. If you will know the shape of the object items in these arrays in advance, you should definitely type them specifically. If you won't, it may be safer to type them as `unknown[]` and make casts based on runtime tests.

Assuming `unknown[]` for now, here's a version of your code with a few things cleaned up to be more TypeScript idiomatic (using the `Record` utility type and `for...of`, plus not accepting the keys as an argument to `createObject` since they should only ever be the keys from `arr`):

```
const arr = [{
  name: 'key1'
}, {
  name: 'key2'
}] as const;

type arrKey = typeof arr[number]['name'];

type Entry = {
  [k in arrKey]: unknown[]
};

const createObject = (): Entry => {
  const obj: Record<string, unknown[]> = {};
  for (const key of arr.map(k => k.name)) {
    obj[key] = [];
  }
  return obj as Entry;
};

const emptyEntry = createObject();
emptyEntry.key1.push({
  pushedItem: 'pushedItem1'
});
```

([TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gbwFAxmOAWwFMAuGAcgGtiBPARguwF8AaGHPAk86ugJibMAuvAgxQkKAG5s2KLQAOxeEgDSdVDAXKQAM1UJ0YAK6EARsQTD0FbsQrDZ8pSoCiYKAlpbOGKjAAlmCGGrTC5CZgVGAgAO5g6MIszpLQEgjEcFDEAPLmAFbEwLBoABQAlOQeXj4oAHwcuBLg6SCF5ABKxSAIACYAPNAIwQDm7FEx8YnCjWiYzLJ4er0wZWmwND76hgB0hHCKZQENMFS79hUVTXh47QXoW6JoSUswzM2ZUCYIIfdiMBq3lkizkGxgxEIigUQLqGSyOXyRRKlVkkOhtFhuy29F2ihMEAAFmU-PiicQ+gBJHKEXhkwkU6mQxgsCrSIA))